# 'sales_flat_order_grid' shows wrong data

Tags: order-grid

In my clients store there are 4 orders that are displaying wrong data, all four consecutive orders are displaying the same billing and shipping name in the order grid, all other data is correct.

I've gone through all 3rd party extensions and none seem to mutate that table so I guess the issue originates from somewhere in the Magento core code.
I was wondering if anyone else has ever encountered this.
It's only those 4 orders and in the order grid, orders after them have not had this issue and invoice and shipping grid do show the correct data.

Comment: have you checked if there is any override in local directory affecting this?

Comment: I did, wasn't it either. It's actually quite strange

Comment: i don't think it has anything to do with Magento core. You can check disabling local and community extensions though to make sure.

Comment: That will be the next step but I'll need to set up a testing environment. I was hoping someone recognized the issue. Ill let you know if I find anything

Comment: Did you find the problem here? Share it with us!

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt sorry for not responding earlier to this thread, i've been abroad for work. I tracked the issue down after a lot of debugging to a 3th party using the WSDL API.
Actually I had my suspicions but I needed some proof so build a couple of custom loggers that checked for the data send via the WSDL.
So no issues in Magento, just 'human error'

Comment: can you please write it down as an answer and mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked the issue down after a lot of debugging to a 3th party using the WSDL API. Actually I had my suspicions but I needed some proof so build a couple of custom loggers that checked for the data send via the WSDL. So no issues in Magento, just 'human error'